# How to turn off intermediary results in a function in Octave

Tags: octave

When I define a function in Octave, every time a variable is re-assigned, it would display the new variable in the console. Example, with a function:

```
function retval = doSomeMath (x)
  retval = 0
  x = x * 2
  x = x + 5
  retval = x
endfunction
```

The console would display:

```
>> doSomeMath(1)
retval = 0
x =  2
x =  7
retval =  7
ans =  7
```

But a function such as Integral would just display the answer. Is there anyway to make it only display the ans and not the other results?

Comment: Add a semicolon ; at the end of  each statement.

Comment: https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Simple-Examples.html#Elementary-Calculations   Ending a command with a semicolon tells Octave not to print the result of the command.